# Looping Through Objects with for ... in

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

javascript beginner. 
"The for...in" question.

Applied to an array object, but days cannot be defined.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Loops and Control</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>
  var days = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'];
  var message = "";
  for (i in days) {
  message += 'Day ' + i + ' is' 
  day[i] + '\n';
  }
 alert(message);
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? You are missing a `+` and `day` should be `days`. Your browser's console should tell you what is wrong.

Comment: it is not object it is an array. and try using reduce instead of loop

Comment: Use map or `for (var i=0;i<days.length;i++)` and use days[i]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems there:

1. You've tried to use `day[i]`, but you have no `day` variable (it's called `days`).
2. `for-in` isn't meant for looping through array entries; [details of your various options here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476).
3. You're missing a `+` after `' is'`
4. Your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)* — you need to declare `i`.

So:

```js
var days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
var message = "";
for (var i = 0; i < days.length; ++i) {
  message += 'Day ' + i + ' is ' + days[i] + '\n';
}
alert(message);
```

Alternately, array have several features that you can use to do operations on their entries. There's [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), which loops through the entries:

```js
var days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
var message = "";
days.forEach(function(day, i) {
  message += 'Day ' + i + ' is ' + days[i] + '\n';
});
alert(message);
```

...or [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), which is meant for exactly this use case: Building up a result from the array's entries:

```js
var days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
var message = days.reduce(function(m, day, i) {
  return m + 'Day ' + i + ' is ' + days[i] + '\n';
}, "");
alert(message);
```

Comment: You are great. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Micco: No worries. I missed out something, so I've added #4 above.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `for` loop to iterate through Arrays. `For in` is not recommended for Arrays.

Otherwise you can also use `forEach`

```js
var days = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'];
var message = [];

for(var i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
   message.push('Day', (i + 1), 'is', days[i] + '\n');
}

alert(message.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the array is misspelled inside the for. It should be:

```
for (i in days) {
    message += 'Day ' + i + ' is' + days[i] + '\n';
}
```

`i` will take the value of the index, and you use it to access the original array

Comment: It is not recommended to use for..in for arrays

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with reduce method of the array

```js
const days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
const newLine = (acc, curr) => acc += curr + '\n';
const message = days.reduce(newLine, '');
console.log(message)
```

Comment: OP is a beginner. ES6 is not for beginners

Comment: @mplungjan.. this guy is obsessed by ramda .  Walk through his answers to note that